# How to copy only the files from a directory that match the file names in a .csv

Tags: c#, csv, file, directory, copy

I have a .csv file that contains file names and I need to find in a directory the files that match the file names in the .csv and copy them to another directory.

I don`t know how to do this?

.csv file contains:

```
11420511800.png
11455010100.png
11455010120.png
11455010140.png
11455010150.png
11455010200.png
11455010250.png
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working for you? Also what exactly you don't know how to achieve? How to open a file? How to read a csv? How to move file?

Comment: @Guru Stron, i got the file names in a .csv file, but i don`t know how to match the file names with the ones in a directory and if there is a match to copy all files in a new directory.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, it helps a bit.

Comment: I would suggest to look into [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-5.0) method for starters.

Comment: @GuruStron I will look into it, i need to. This was urgent for me and didn`t had time to study, test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var allowedFiles = File.ReadAllLines(@"X:\your-csv-path-goes-here.csv");
var filesToCopy = new DirectoryInfo(@"Y:\your-source-directory").GetFiles()
                 .Where(f => allowedFiles.Any(af => f.Name.Equals(af, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
foreach (var fileInfo in filesToCopy) {
   var destFilePath = Path.Combine("Z:\your-destination-directory", fileInfo.Name);
   fileInfo.CopyTo(destFilePath, true); //true => overwrite existing files
}
```

Comment: This is what i need but i get an IO exception:
"System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=5
  Message=The target file "C:\Users\touda\OneDrive\Shopia\Proiecte\PRB Shop SRL\Fisiere produse\Imagini produse\img site" is a directory, not a file."

Comment: `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`what if code is running on Linux?

Comment: @DanileTou Thx for the feedback, I didn't test it. So you need to specify the full destination file path not just the directory. I've edited my post

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\")`

That command gets you all the files in a Directory (as a List).

You can iterate through that list and compare it with the names in your .csv file (if you have them in a list [or something similar] too).